# Unable to get SelectedItems through Xceed CheckListBox using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, xceed, checklistbox

I have been using wpf xceed third party library for some of the UI components. I really like the way CheckListBox is being displayed at the screen. But I am not able to get the selectedItems bound to any property in the viewmodel (the setter never triggers). Here is the code -

I am using a dataprovider to get values from enum -

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="DeviceClassDataProvider">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="Model:HANDeviceClass" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

And then the control has been declared something like this -

```
<ext:CheckListBox Focusable="False" SelectedMemberPath="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedDeviceGroups, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.Column="4" Padding="5" BorderThickness="0.8" BorderBrush="Gray" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DeviceClassDataProvider}}"/>
```

How will i get the selected items in it's viewmodel?

Any quick help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work provided that `SelectedDeviceGroups` is a public property that returns an `ICollection<HANDeviceClass>`:

```
public ICollection<HANDeviceClass> SelectedDeviceGroups { get; } = new ObservableCollection<HANDeviceClass>();
```

**XAML:**

```
<ext:CheckListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DeviceClassDataProvider}}"
                  SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedDeviceGroups}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDeviceGroups.Count}" />
```

Items will be added to and removed from the source collection as you check and uncheck items respectively.

Comment: Well I was having a breakpoint at the setter and it never hits that. Seems like getter works. Thanks :)